# Adding values to variables in data structure from file in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I'm working on a program that will eventually evaluate bridge hands, but I'm getting stuck on one of the first steps. I am supposed to read in a file like this one:

```
2C QD TC AD 6C 3D TD 3H 5H 7H AS JH KH
3C 4C 2D AC QC 7S 7C TD 9C 4D KS 8D 6C
2C 3C KC JC 4C 8C 7C QC AC 5C 9C 6C TC
5H 3S 4D KC 9S 3D 4S 8H JC TC 8S 2S 4C
2S 5D 6S 8S 9D 3C 2H TH
2H 6D %S 8S 7S 4D 3H 4S KS QH JH 5C 9S
2C QD TC AD 6C 3D TD 3C 5H 7H AS JH KD QS
2C QD TC AD 6C 3D TD 2C 5D 7H AS JH KD
2H 6D TS 8Z 7S 4D 3H 4S KS QD JH 5C 9S
```

Each line in the file represents 1 hand of 13 cards. As you can see, there are some lines with more or less than 13 cards, but this is supposed to be taken care of later with error handling.

I also need a data structure to hold the cards in an organized manner. My question is this:

How am I supposed to assign the values from the file to the variables in my data structure? I'm probably overthinking it, but I'm getting really thrown off by the fact that the input is in pairs (the first character is the value and the second is the suit). I'm pretty sure once I get the card (value + suit) stored into the data structure, I can use an array of store the cards into hands and then continue with the rest of my program, I'm just stuck on the data structure part.

Here is what code I have so far:

```
struct hand {
    char value;
    char suit;
};

int main() {
    ifstream bridgeFile;
    bridgeFile.open("prog3.dat");
    if(!bridgeFile) {
        cerr << "Open Failure" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        cout << "File is open" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `cout << "File is open" << endl;` line with this solution and it should put your each "hand" in a `vector<hand>` element of `bridgeHands`:

```
vector<vector<hand>> bridgeHands;
string line;
for(getline(bridgeFile,line);bridgeFile.good();getline(bridgeFile,line)){
    vector<hand> bridgeHand;
    for(auto iter = line.begin();iter < line.end();iter += 2){
        hand handIter;
        handIter.value = *iter;
        ++iter;
        handIter.suit = *iter;
        bridgeHand.push_back(handIter);
    }
    bridgeHands.push_back(bridgeHand);
}
```

This could be made a lot safer by adding an `operator<<` to your `struct hand` rather than reading in `char` by `char` and hoping that you haven't gotten a bad file.

I didn't want to spend too much time on that cause it could probably use a makeover, you'd do a lot better if you used an `enum` to define ALL your cards and simply read in two characters for each card.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to read this one character at a time. There'd be a for loop running fr 13 iterations. Each iteration would read 3 characters. The first would be translated into the value with an expression like:

(c>'0' && c<='9') ? c-'0' : c=='J' ? 10 ....

The second character maps similarly to the suit and the third is required to be space most of the time but newline on the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

- read whole line at a time.
- If length of string ( i.e line ) !=38 (13+13+12space) Throw error , not all suits available
- else i=0 && 
  `while(i<lenghtOfLine) 
  { 
  value = line[i] ;
  suit = line [i+1] ;
  i=i+2; 
  // Pass them to structures 
  }`
- Read Next line and repeat

Comment: This looks great. On the // Pass them to structures part, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Just Assign them to any data structure or array , you have implemented to store.